# How do I programmatically (C++) check the code signing date of an EXE in Windows?

Tags: c++, date, code-signing

Is this possible?  How do I go about doing it?  Does it require admin rights? (I would not think so)

A pointer to a help page or link is fine - no need to provide code.  Given my difficulty with  he code signing cert and setting it up in our build environment I am not sure I am googling with the right terms.

EDIT

After some searching I did find some possible sample code

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323809/en-us

I will try it out.

Comment: Depends on how you're code signing. You can set the timestamp in the executable before signing it, and Authenticode will catch that. I don't think StrongName signing (for CLR executables) looks for that kind of thing though.

Comment: I know I can set the timestamp when I sign it.  In fact we do.  What I want to do is check programmatically at some time in the future what the signed date is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either [`WinVerifyTrust`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388208.aspx) or [`SetupScanFileQueue(SPQ_SCAN_USE_CALLBACK_SIGNERINFO)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377435.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I will have to go look for some sample code.  I can't make heads or tails of how to go about doing what I want using the information in those links.

Comment: Sample code is provided for WinVerifyTrust; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382384(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at MSFT's [authenticode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537364%28VS.85%29.aspx)?